# Yes and No as the output for the condition in logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a simple requirement , In logic app trigger I am getting a variable called suspendschedule and I want to make

if(suspendschedule == true  then value should be Yes
if suspendschedule  == false then the value should be No

and this is what I am trying
[image]

`@if(equals(triggerBody()?['_suspendschedule],"false"),"No","Yes")`

Comment: Hi Suppose I want to write it as the  separate if  true and false ? how to write like if(A) then 1 , IF (B) then 2???

Answer (score 1):

if your suspendschedule is a type of bool then Try these

first, check for the true condition because if the field is null or missing in triggerBody it will go in else

```
@if(equals(triggerBody()?['suspendschedule'],bool(1)),'Yes','No')
```

if it is in string format or you are not sure try this it will check both bool and string

first, check for the true condition because if the field is null or missing in triggerBody it will go in else

```
@if(equals(triggerBody()?['suspendschedule'],'true'),'Yes','No')
```